# Is it possible to do Paypal payment in 2 parts and hold the payment until the service completed

Tags: php, paypal

Can anyone help me with paypal payment integration in such a way that:

A payment for a service can be splited into two parts.

First part will be go into admin's account. And another will be on hold until task is completed by provider.

When task is completed then only payment will be transfered to the Service Provider.

Is this possible with paypal payment method in PHP?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you located to any of offered country for Marketplace, you can try to apply for Marketplace. You can read further in here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/.

Previously PayPal has this service called Adaptive Payment however PayPal has taken a decision to sunset the app from current market.